# SQLite - ошибка database is locked

Tags: c#, sqlite

Добрый день, или вечер, или другое время суток.
Суть проблемы - C# + SQLite, метод сохраняющий данные в таблице с клиентами выглядит так:

```
public void AddClient(Client client)
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + this._databaseFileName + ";");

        connection.Open();
        try
        { 
            string query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE passport_series='" + client.PassportSeries + "' AND passport_number='" + client.PassportNumber + "';";
            SQLiteDataReader reader = this._executeQueryReader(query, connection);

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                throw new Exception("Паспорт " + client.PassportSeries + " №" + client.PassportNumber + " уже есть в базе данных");
            }

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            query = "INSERT INTO client (first_name, middle_name, last_name, passport_series, passport_number) VALUES (" +
                       "'" + client.FirstName + "', " +
                       "'" + client.MiddleName + "', " +
                       "'" + client.LastName + "', " +
                       "'" + client.PassportSeries + "', " +
                       "'" + client.PassportNumber + "');";

            this._executeQuery(query, connection);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            connection.Close();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

При втором вызове метода - оказывается что `database is locked` на втором запросе. При этом если вызов первый - то все отрабатывает хорошо. Если же при первом было выброшено исключение `"Паспорт " + client.PassportSeries + " №" + client.PassportNumber + " уже есть в базе данных"`, то при повторном вызове первый запрос показывает, что все ок, исключение не вылетает - и второй запрос натыкается на залоченную БД. Поток один (мультипотоки здесь никаким боком не присутствуют). Сломал голову - как добиться чтоб после первого запроса `SELECT` второй `INSERT` мог выполниться сразу? Закомментированный вызов `sleep` помогал, но только если сон длится не менее 10 секунд - это долго для простенького десктоп-приложения. Как разлочить БД сразу после селекта?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте using для SQLiteConnection и SQLiteDataReader
Проблема это незакрытый ридер.

```
public void AddClient(Client client)
{
     using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + this._databaseFileName + ";"))
     {
         connection.Open();
         string query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE passport_series='" + client.PassportSeries + "' AND passport_number='" + client.PassportNumber + "';";
         using(var reader = this._executeQueryReader(query, connection))
         {
             if (reader.HasRows)
             {
                 throw new Exception("Паспорт " + client.PassportSeries + " №" + client.PassportNumber + " уже есть в базе данных");
             }
             query = "INSERT INTO client (first_name, middle_name, last_name, passport_series, passport_number) VALUES (" +
                        "'" + client.FirstName + "', " +
                        "'" + client.MiddleName + "', " +
                        "'" + client.LastName + "', " +
                        "'" + client.PassportSeries + "', " +
                        "'" + client.PassportNumber + "');";

             this._executeQuery(query, connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Еще лучше и так как это на самом деле нужно делать, хранимая процедура и вызов хранимой процедуры с передачей параметров.

```
throw ex; - обрезает стек, так писать не стоит throw;
```